# CUDA memory allocation - is it efficient

Tags: cuda

This is my code. I have lot of threads so that those threads calling this function many times. 
Inside this function I am creating an array. It is an efficient implementation?? If it is not please suggest me the efficient implementation.

```
__device__ float calculate minimum(float *arr)
 {
     float vals[9];      //for each call to this function I am creating this arr
                        // Is it efficient?? Or how can I implement this efficiently?
                        // Do I need to deallocate the memory after using this array?
     for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
         vals[i] = //call some function and assign the values
     float min = findMin(vals);
     return min;
 }
```

Comment: @mbx: This is CUDA. There is no stack by default, functions are compiled inline.

Comment: So should efficient anyway :-) Thanks for your advice. I'll better delete my first comment to not confuse other readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "array creation" in that code. There is a statically declared array. Further, the standard CUDA compilation model will inline expand `__device__`functions, meaning that the `vals` will be compiled to be in local memory, or if possible even in registers.

All of this happens at compile time, not run time.

Comment: @Green Code: Yes, obviously. This is a `__device__`function - it compiles to inline GPU code within the CUDA kernel that calls it. There are four types of memory in that compilation model - global, shared, constant and local.

Comment: Could you explain more about these memories and what specifications they have and what is their size (I just asked a same question in gamedev.stackexchange)?

Comment: That is all covered in great detail in the CUDA programming guide if you care to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something, but from the code you have posted, you don't need the temporary array at all. Your code will be (a little) faster if you do something like this:

```
 #include "float.h" // for FLT_MAX

__device__ float calculate minimum(float *arr)
 {
     float minVal = FLT_MAX:
     for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
         thisVal = //call some function and assign the values
         minVal = min(thisVal,minVal);
     return minVal;
 }
```

Where an array is actually required, there is nothing wrong with declaring it in this way (as many others have said).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "float vals[9]", this will be efficient in CUDA.  For arrays that have small size, the compiler will almost surely allocate all the elements into registers directly.  So "vals[0]" will be a register, "vals[1]" will be a register, etc.

If the compiler starts to run out of registers, or the array size is larger than around 16, then local memory is used.  You don't have to worry about allocating/deallocating local memory, the compiler/driver do all that for you.

Devices of compute capability 2.0 and greater do have a call stack to allow things like recursion.  For example you can set the stack size to 6KB per thread with:

```
cudaStatus = cudaThreadSetLimit(cudaLimitStackSize, 1024*6);
```

Normally you won't need to touch the stack yourself.  Even if you put big static arrays in your device functions, the compiler and driver will see what's there and make space for you.

Comment: This is not completely correct.  If the array is dynamically indexed, the array MUST be stored in device (off-chip) memory, because the GPU register file is not dynamically addressable (register indices must be immediate values in the compiled assembly).  So if `i` in `vals[i]` is dynamically computed, `vals` will not be stored in registers, no matter how small it is.  In the above case, you could `#pragma unroll` the loop, to ensure that `i` is not dynamic.